# Non-usable magic items

Tags: diablo-iii

I beat the game on normal, and I have a lot of magic items in my inventory (where potions are found) and cant find anything to do with them (example: Clever dice of invasion). Obviously they have some use considering they have magical properties such as intelligence and so forth. What im wondering is do they enhance my stats by sitting in my inventory or are they a craft material later on nightmare mode and beyond. what do i do with them?

Comment: Sounds like [follower items](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67635/how-can-you-use-follower-items).

Comment: @Troyen didn't see that in the title I think you are right

Comment: what do i do with them?

Comment: Equip them if they are good for your follower (dice with +dex, mirror with +int, relic with +str), or sell/disenchant them.

Answer (score 5):

The Clever Dice of Invasion is a type of [Scoundrel Token](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/scoundrel-token/), which is a special piece of equipment that the Scoundrel can equip.  There are items for the other followers, like [relics for the Templar](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/templar-relic/) and [focuses for the Enchantress](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/enchantress-focus/).  All of these items should be marked "Follower" where the equipment slot is normally listed.

These items can only provide a benefit to your followers and only do so when equipped. If they're sitting in your inventory, then they are just taking up space, and you probably want to equip, sell, or disenchant them.

To equip your follower, you need to access the [follower inventory screen](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/followers#training-your-followers).  On the PC, you could do this by hitting the <kbd>F</kbd> key or clicking on the follower's portrait in the top-left corner of the screen.  On the console, you need to access the character menu (the Back button on the Xbox) and navigate to the party screen.